# No archetypes currently available. The archetype list will refresh when the indexes finish updating

Tags: maven, m2eclipse, nexus

In Eclipse with **m2eclipse** installed, when I choose

> File > New > Project... > Maven > Maven Project

with

> Use default Workspace location

and

> Catalog: Nexus Indexer

selected, the following error message is showing up:

> No archetypes currently available. The archetype list will refresh when the indexes finish updating.

Why does this error occur?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I had same problem and it was solved by adding a remote catalog:
http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml

This solution i found at :
http://jira.talendforge.org/secure/attachment/36787/DeveloperGuide-Feedback.pdf

Comment: Does Maven works well under a proxy? I tried to add this remote catalog and it says: "Remote Catalog is empty". Copying the url in Chrome shows the xml...

(I have already configured the proxy settings in Eclipse)

Comment: Its https now in stead of http in the link: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml

Comment: In my case I use px (https://github.com/genotrance/px) as local proxy with debug enabled, and I can see Eclipse using the proxy to access the network. The point is that for this archetypes it does not use the proxy at all. Even if I go in the archetype remote definition and press the "Verify" button.

Answer (score 8):

in this case you can use another solution, you need to configure a local ctalogue using eclipse :

1- suppose that you need to use mave catalogue : https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml

2- download from your web broser the file https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml and save it in ~/.m2/archetype-catalog.xml

3 now go to eclipse "Window-->Preferences-->maven-->Archetypes" then click the "Add Local catalogue" and set the ctalogue file to the  ~/.m2/archetype-catalog.xml, save and exit

4- now go back to eclipse and try to create project using your new local catatlogue archetypes, it should work

Comment: Thank I would say this looks mora like a workaround, not a solution, doing so you have to update it manually if the provider updates the definitions or it publishes new archetypes

Answer (score 1):

Updated remote catalog link: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml

Either copy the link and add a remote archetype or download the XML file and go for a local archetype option and follow @sofiene-zaghdoudi 's solution.

Comment: Please add more details to your post for future readers as the contents in the links may expire after some time.