# Can not Convert to Maven Project in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven

I am trying to follow this tutorial: http://crunchify.com/how-to-build-restful-service-with-java-using-jax-rs-and-jersey/

And in step 3, you're supposed to convert your project to a Maven project. However, the option `Convert to Maven Project` does not show at `Right-click > Configure`. I have installed Maven using apt-get. Is there any settings I have forgotten?

I am using `Eclipse Indigo` on `Linux Ubuntu 12.04`.

Comment: Do you have m2e (Maven) plugin for eclipse?

Comment: Yes, I have the plugin installed.

Comment: Try following the steps from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29205958/2587435) to get up and running. The tutorial you are going off uses Jersey 1.x. The link I linked to uses Jersey 2.x, but with the same method, you can select the 1.x archetype to get started.

Answer (score 0):

You need the m2e plugin for eclipse. If you have installed it, you have to do a right klick on your project and there you will find the item  `configure`.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I see that I wrote `File > Configure` in my question. I did right click on my project, choosing `Configure`. Maven does not show up there.

Comment: Did you maybe already import the project as a maven project and resolution is already working?

Comment: I does not seem like it. My project don't contain any pom.xml yet. I am trying to re-install Eclipse at the moment. Maybe I'll have better luck the second time. :)

Comment: Yeah, and be sure you also installed the m2e plugin.

Comment: So my answer was helpful? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what went wrong on my first try. But when I re-installed Eclipse with plug-ins and such (as M2E), it worked.