# Jersey Maven quickstart archetype in Eclipse

Tags: java, maven, jersey, jersey-2.0, maven-archetype

I am trying to create Jersey normally with the aid of maven  but I am always getting this structure as in the scrennshoot and without error as normally?! It does not look as Jersey commonly layout.

I am using this one:

```
org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes
jersey-quickstart-webapp
2.16
```

[image]

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.test</groupId>
  <artifactId>serverSide</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>serverSide</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: You have an _almost empty_ pom.xml with only junit added as test dependency. Can you please explain, what other things did you expect to see in eclipse?

Comment: @npe: As I said I created it with the aid of the eclipse IDE- Maven - Maven  project. Usually I can start without adding any other resource to it I have done it before?!  In the screenshoot, this project instance has been  created by maven! also this behaviour is strange?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I highly doubt you are creating the archetype project correctly. What you are showing is a product of the `org.apache.maven.archetypes : maven-archetype-quickstart`

Here's a quick walk-through of how to create the Jersey archetype in Eclipse

1. Go to `File` → `New` → `Other`
2. In the dialog, select the `Maven` file the `Maven Project`, then <kbd>Next</kbd>

   [image]
3. In the next dialog keep all the defaults, and hit <kbd>Next</kbd>

   [image]
4. In this next dialog we will select the Maven archetype. In the search box, type `jersey-quickstart-webapp`. All the archetypes takes a few moments to load. You can see the progress at the bottom right of the IDE is they are still loading. This shouldn't take more than maybe 5 seconds. If you are not seeing any results come up from the search, then it's likely you don't have the archetypes installed. See [this Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29116241/2587435) for how you can get the archetypes.

   Once the archetypes load, and you see the `jersey-quickstart-webapp` in the results list, uncheck "Show the last version of Archetype only". So once you have unchecked that, you should see more version available. Scroll down to the `org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes` and select the version 2.16 (or whatever the latest version is, if you choose). Then hit <kbd>Next</kbd>

   [image]
5. In the next dialog, enter the groupId, artifactId, and package, then hit <kbd>Finish</kbd>

   [image]
6. You should now see a project with the following structure. There will be an error in the project because of you jsp page. We have no use for it here, so you can delete it if you want. This should get rid of the error.

   [image]

---

**See Also:**

- [Getting Started with Jersey 2](http://paulsamsotha.blogspot.com/2015/10/getting-started-with-jersey-2.html)

Comment: I have already did the same but what helped me is tte fourth point with the stackoverflow answer link :) Thanks.

Comment: Anyone knows how to achieve the equivalence of this with Gradle?

Comment: @PabloQ [this is pretty much all you need](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27890414/2587435)

Comment: @peeskillet I did the above steps mentioned by you, but I was unable to run this on the sever (tomcat 7). When I tried to add the resource, I get a message no resources found. Kindly suggest me what should be done to run this type of project on server.

Comment: To add to my previous comment - I had downloaded jersey-quickstart-grizzly2 v 2.22.2

Comment: `jersey-quickstart-webapp` was not appearing for me. So I followed [Adding org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31721013/adding-org-glassfish-jersey-archetypes-in-eclipse)

Comment: After doing this and restarting ecllipse, the archetypes for jersey show in the list, however if I select jersey-quickstart-webapp archetype and provide my group Id, artifact ID and version, all I get is error "cant resolve archetype org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes:jersey-quickstart-webapp:2.30.1"

Answer (score 9):

**One point I want to add, If you are getting following error while installing the archetype showed in image 1**

> Can't resolve Archetype
>   org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes:jersey-quickstart-webapp:2.21
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Could not resolve artifact
>   org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes:jersey-quickstart-webapp:pom:2.21

Image 1:
[image]

**Then before procedding with the solution specified in [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29114936/how-do-i-find-the-correct-maven-archetype-project-for-developing-with-scala-in-e/29116241#29116241), try to complete the following steps in eclipse:**

**Steps:**

1. Go to Eclipse **Help** -> **Install New Software...**
2. Enter "http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases" inside **Work with** field and click on **Add** button.
3. Give any name. For example "*remote archetypes*" and click on **OK** button.
   [image]
4. Then click on **Select All** button.
   [image]
5. click **Next** button two times.
6. Accept the licence and install the updated maven.

Answer (score 0):

*Can't resolve Archetype org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes:jersey-quickstart-webapp:2.21 org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Could not resolve artifact org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes:jersey-quickstart-webapp:pom:2.21*

**To resolve the issues with respect to archetypes while creating a new maven project ,please follow the same.**

Navigate as follows in your Eclipse IDE,

Hover to windows-->Click on Preferences

*Search for maven and select Archetype(first option under the hood as in screen shot)*
[image]

- Click on Add Remote catalog on the same
- In catalog file text box,Enter the following:
  [http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NSf2.png)

This above URL could be changed in future;in that case please refer the below link under **location of catalog files** for latest URL http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/specification/archetype-catalog.html

- Under Description,enter your own description of choice & click ok & apply the main menu.

Give eclipse sometime to load your archetypes.(Check progress menu for the download status)

And this worked out for me. Thanks

[image]