# 404 error with Rest Service - Jersey/tomcat8

Tags: java, rest, maven, tomcat, jersey

I have been trying this for the past couple of days with many examples, I am not able to make the REST service running.  I have tomcat8(Ubuntu 14.x)/Jersey.
Any idea?

pom.xml snippet

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

web.xml snippet

```
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>RestService</servlet-name>
    <!--servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class-->
<servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
             <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
<!--param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name-->
        <param-value>mail.service</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>RestService</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

No errors on tomcat startup:

> 11-Jul-2015 11:23:08.327 INFO [localhost-startStop-8]
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate
>   Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.18.1 02/19/2014
>   03:28 AM' 11-Jul-2015 11:23:08.795 INFO [localhost-startStop-8]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web
>   application archive
>   /home/apcuser/tomcat8/apache-tomcat-8.0.24/webapps/ExProcess.war has
>   finished in 1,488 ms

Rest service class:

```
package mail.service;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Request;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;

//import org.slf4j.Logger;
//import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

@Path("restservice")
public class RestService {
        @Context
        UriInfo uriInfo;
        @Context
        Request request;
        String id;

        @GET
        @Path("{name}")
        public String sayHello(@PathParam("name") String name){
            return "Hello " + name;
        }

}
```

Result:

> HTTP Status 404 - /rest/restservice/TestName

Update: I couldn't figure out whats wrong with my project, just started from scratch following : http://javabrains.koushik.org/courses/javaee_jaxrs/lessons/Setting-Up
It works now.

Comment: Start over and go [off this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30020830/2587435) and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Path("/restservice")
public class RestService {
        @Context
        UriInfo uriInfo;
        @Context
        Request request;
        String id;

        @GET
        @Path("/{name}")
        @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
        public String sayHello(@PathParam("name") String name){
            return "Hello " + name;
        }

}
```

http 404 is file not found error, you are getting this because you didn't append `/` to the `@Path` annotation value.

`@Path("restservice")` should be `@Path("/restservice")` and `@Path("{name}")` should be `@Path("/{name}")`

**EDIT Update-**

added `@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)`

Comment: Tried this too, didn't work.  How can I figure out whether my class is loaded by tomcat?

Comment: check /WEB-INF/classes in target folder, if the .class files are there or not.  Second check webapps folder, expand the war and see if   .class files exist in /WEB-INF/class

Comment: hey whats the exact url you are trying to hit?

Comment: I checked those, the classes are there.

Comment: localhost:8080/ipaddr/rest/restservice/somename ?? is "ipaddr" the app context root name??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83017/discussion-between-user1882828-and-sudhansu-choudhary).

Comment: Thanks Sudhansu for your help, I am able to get it running, just started from scratch following the tutorial: http://javabrains.koushik.org/courses/javaee_jaxrs/lessons/Setting-Up

Answer (score -1):

You try following

Changes in web.xml

```
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>RestService</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

and in servlet

```
@Path("/rest/restservice/")
public class RestService {
        @Context
        UriInfo uriInfo;
        @Context
        Request request;
        String id;

        @GET
        @Path("/{name}/")
        public String sayHello(@PathParam("name") String name){
            return "Hello " + name;
        }

}
```

Also I see you have commented the code. But have you cleared webapps directory? Stop the tomcat container -> Go to webapps directory -> Delete folder ExProcess (not war) -> Start container.

Comment: Aniket, I was following some samples and in that web.xml had these entries.  [please see this example](http://www.java4s.com/web-services/jersey-hello-world-example-using-jax-rs-specification/)

Comment: Aniket, the servlet will handle `/rest/restservice/` as the url pattern is `/rest/*` and OP has mentioned `@Path("restservice")` which actually should be `@Path("/restservice")` in RestService.

Comment: Also, `RestService` servlet name is fine as far as `<servlet-name>` in `</servlet>` and `<servlet-mapping>` are same, in this case pointing to `com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer`

Comment: Ok but how will server container know `RestService ` class should handle the request?  if serverlet class we specifiy points to `com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer` ?

Comment: I thought it does a scanning (evident from the logs) and the annotations given in my class.

Comment: Yup you have provided it `<param-value>mail.service</param-value>`, So your package `mail.service` will be scanner which does have RestService class.

Comment: @user1882828 I see you have commented the code. But have you cleared webapps directory? Stop the tomcat container -> Go to webapps directory -> Delete folder ExProcess (not war) -> Start container.