# 404 error when running Jersey web app on Tomcat 7 in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, rest, maven, tomcat

Trying to create a simple RESTful web service using Jersey and deploying it on Tomcat 7. Since I'm new to web app development in Java and eager to learn it, I'm following [this tutorial](https://javabrains.io/courses/javaee_jaxrs/lessons/Setting-Up/%22example%20tutorial%22).

I created this app as a Maven project in Eclipse and used the `jersey-quickstart-webapp` artifact version `2.22.2` with `org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes` groupID. Note that I had to later change the Project Facet to `Dynamic Web Module` else it wouldn't give me an option to deploy it to the local Tomcat server.

I"ve added my `messenger` app as a resource in Tomcat server. I don't see any error when I start the Tomcat server within Eclipse. There is just one WARNING 
`WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:messenger' did not find a matching property.`, which, according to lots of SO posts, can be safely ignored.

After right-clicking on the app and clicking `Run As` -> `Run on Server`, I see a 404 page not found for the URL `http://localhost:8080/messenger/` as well as `http://localhost:8080/webapi/myresource`.

Checked a lot of similar SO posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16845581/404-when-accessing-jersey-app-in-tomcat-7) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31354059/404-error-with-rest-service-jersey-tomcat8?rq=1) but they didn't help.

One thing I noticed is that the `web.xml` inside `<peoject_root>/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/ROOT/WEB-INF` doesn't match with my app's web.xml(Not sure if it should match, after the app gets deployed to Tomcat). Infact the content under that dir is copied below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
```

Need some pointers on what might be wrong. It might be something simple but I've spent a lot of time on this scratching my head and getting the same 404 error for the n'th time. I was hoping to get this simple app to work before I get some confidence and continue watching the training videos.

Adding some more detail via screenshots and file contents:

**MyResource.java**

```
package org.testapp.java.messenger;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

/**
 * Root resource (exposed at "myresource" path)
 */
@Path("myresource")
public class MyResource {

    /**
     * Method handling HTTP GET requests. The returned object will be sent
     * to the client as "text/plain" media type.
     *
     * @return String that will be returned as a text/plain response.
     */
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getIt() {
        return "Got it!";
    }
}
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- This web.xml file is not required when using Servlet 3.0 container,
     see implementation details http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/jax-rs.html -->
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>org.testapp.java.messenger</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/webapi/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**project structure**

[image]

**Tomcat error**

[image]

One RED cross you see in the code is acutally `The superclass "javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet" was not found on the Java Build Path` which the instructor in the tutorial video asks to ignore since Tomcat provides the HTTPServlet class.

**console output**

```
May 01, 2016 10:09:20 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:messenger' did not find a matching property.
May 01, 2016 10:09:20 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/7.0.69
May 01, 2016 10:09:20 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Apr 11 2016 07:57:09 UTC
May 01, 2016 10:09:20 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         7.0.69.0
May 01, 2016 10:09:20 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Mac OS X
May 01, 2016 10:09:20 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            10.10.2
May 01, 2016 10:09:20 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          x86_64
May 01, 2016 10:09:20 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
May 01, 2016 10:09:20 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_31-b13
May 01, 2016 10:09:20 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
May 01, 2016 10:09:20 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         /Users/abc/Personal/Java/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0
May 01, 2016 10:09:20 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         /Users/abc/Personal/Java/apache-tomcat-7.0.69
May 01, 2016 10:09:20 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/Users/abc/Personal/Java/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0
May 01, 2016 10:09:20 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/Users/abc/Personal/Java/apache-tomcat-7.0.69
May 01, 2016 10:09:20 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=/Users/abc/Personal/Java/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps
May 01, 2016 10:09:20 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/Users/abc/Personal/Java/apache-tomcat-7.0.69/endorsed
May 01, 2016 10:09:20 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
May 01, 2016 10:09:20 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /Users/abc/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.
May 01, 2016 10:09:20 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
May 01, 2016 10:09:20 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
May 01, 2016 10:09:20 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 434 ms
May 01, 2016 10:09:20 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
May 01, 2016 10:09:20 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.69
May 01, 2016 10:09:20 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
May 01, 2016 10:09:20 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
May 01, 2016 10:09:20 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 269 ms
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.testapp.java</groupId>
    <artifactId>messenger</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>messenger</name>

    <build>
        <finalName>messenger</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <!-- use the following artifactId if you don't need servlet 2.x compatibility -->
            <!-- artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId -->
        </dependency>
        <!-- uncomment this to get JSON support
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        -->
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <jersey.version>2.22.2</jersey.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Comment: Could you post the console output, while facing this issue. It would be assisting in narrow down the issue.

Comment: @ClementAmarnath Thanks for looking into this! I've updated the post with the console output.

Comment: This is server startup and you are not getting any exception in the console while hitting your service!!!

Comment: did you try http://localhost:8080/messenger/webapi/myresource ?

Comment: @ClementAmarnath Yeah no exceptions when hitting the service. What might be the cause?

Comment: @redoc Yeah! Tried that url as well. Same 404 error.

Comment: can u paste here your pom.xml ?

Comment: @OhadR added pom.xml in the original post

Comment: did you try http://localhost:8080/messenger/myresource ?

Comment: what is the name of your `war` that is deployed in tomact. If it is deployed as `example.war` then your path would be `\example\webapi\myresource`. Paths you define in the project's annotations are relative to the `context root`

Comment: The artifact id in my pom.xml is "messenger", so I'm assuming that the war filename is "messenger.war". Sorry but can you tell me how to confirm this?

Answer (score 7):

I faced a similar problem and realized Jersey Version 3.0.0-M6 and Tomcat 9 were incompatible.

Reason --> Tomcat 9 uses javax.servlet.Filter. Jersey 3.x, part of Jakarta EE 9, depends on jakarta based API packages. jakarta.servlet.Filter is available in Tomcat 10.

Solution--> Downloading Tomcat 10 and using it. OR Using Jersey Version 2.X with Tomcat 9 or below.

I personally used Jersey 2.16 with Tomcat 9 and it worked for me.

Comment: The weirdest part is, as suggested by many SO answers, I tried with 2.35 but still was facing same issue. Finally I deleted server configuration and project both and created as you suggested 2.16+tomcat 9 and it worked

Answer (score 1):

Add the below line in your web.xml, before the servlet entry
`<display-name>messenger</display-name>`

Now try your service
http://localhost:8080/messenger/myresource.

Comment: Tried that too! Didn't work. I'm guessing that the "war" itself is not deployed to tomcat properly. Is there a way to confirm this hypothesis? Something specific in the tomcat log I should look for etc.?

Answer (score 1):

I too had faced the same problem while following that tutorial,tried out several things, yet it wouldn't work.
Finally when I downgraded the version to 2.6(partial trial and error) it displayed the "Got it" text as response.I had initially selected the latest version 3.0.0-M6 for the Jersey archetype.

Comment: That's it. Thanks @anuvab-b

Answer (score -1):

**Update:**

I tried deploying my app on Jetty instead, by adding the following plugin to my build section in pom.xml.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>6.1.10</version>
</plugin>
```

and then running `mvn jetty:run` from the Terminal. Now I can successfully access my web app at `http://localhost:8080/messenger/webapi/myresource`. It returns `Got it!` as expected.

So, its definitely a problem in the manner I am deploying it to tomcat. I am interested in debugging the tomcat issue further if anybody has some pointers.