# Adding org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, rest, maven, glassfish

I am trying to create a maven project in eclipse. I am trying create a archetype but getting the below error.

> Can't resolve Archetype org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes:jersey-quickstart-webapp:2.16
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Could not resolve artifact   org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes:jersey-quickstart-webapp:pom:2.16

Comment: Have you done a clean install?

Comment: Yes, try clean install and check whether the version 2.16 of `jersey-quickstart-webapp` exists

Comment: I have tried that but still the error exists. Please let me know how to add org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes in eclipse?

Answer (score 67):

You can solve this issue by adding a new Maven Archetype.

1. Open `Window > Preferences`
2. Open `Maven > Archetypes`
3. Click `Add Remote Catalog` and add the following:

   - *Catalog File*: `https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml`
   - *Description*: `maven catalog`
4. Restart eclipse

Try creating a maven project again. It will work :).

```
{search filter:jersey-quickstart-webapp}
```

You will have the latest version.

Comment: This is a bad idea, after doing this now I cannot even see my catalog archetypes. bad answer be aware.

Comment: @Shrek, you can always select 'All Catalogs' from the drop down while selecting the archetype. This in fact , is the best posible solution.

Comment: After Step 3, we should click "Verify" button to force Eclipse download archetypes.

Comment: Tried but I cannot even see my catalog archetypes

Comment: A simple restart of Eclipse is required to reflect the list of archetypes.

Comment: No archetypes available for this catalog.

Comment: @LinhLino : Clicking verify says "Remote catalog is empty"

Comment: After doing this and restarting ecllipse, the archetypes for jersey show in the list, however if I select jersey-quickstart-webapp archetype and provide my group Id, artifact ID and version, all I get is error "cant resolve archetype org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes:jersey-quickstart-webapp:2.30.1"

Answer (score 14):

Steps

1. Open Eclipse
2. Choose `New > Project > Maven Project`
3. Choose `Add Archetype` and enter the following details:

   - Archetype Group ID: `org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes`
   - Archetype Artifact ID: `jersey-quickstart-webapp`
   - Archetype Version: `2.16` [enter the latest version that is available]
4. Choose the newly entered archetype from the Archetype selection screen
5. Enter your project details - `Group ID`, `Artifact ID` and
   `Version`.

More Information: https://javabrains.io/courses/javaee_jaxrs/lessons/Setting-Up

Comment: Latest version is 2.26 (Oct 2017)

Comment: its working faster than the sreejetih answer - using eclipse neon

Comment: After doing this and restarting ecllipse, the archetypes for jersey show in the list, however if I select jersey-quickstart-webapp archetype and provide my group Id, artifact ID and version, all I get is error "cant resolve archetype org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes:jersey-quickstart-webapp:2.30.1"

Answer (score 10):

You can solve this issue by adding a new Maven Archetype ***locally***. By locally, I mean-

1. Go to this [URL](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml) and download the XML file at your local file system.
2. Open `Window > Preferences`
3. Open `Maven > Archetypes`
4. Click Add Local Catalog > Browse to the location of your `archetype-catalog.xml` file
5. Add Descritpion

   6. OK

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Due to proxy issues, I couldn't use the remote option so tried this one. But still it says : "No archetypes available for this catalog". Any clue?

Comment: maybe also proxy issues with me (Neon 3, 4.6.3, m2e 1.7.1), although it worked in earlier Eclipse versions (Kepler?). I could open the following URLs in the browser and the proxy works for other Eclipse plugins: https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/archetype-catalog.xml, http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml  ... it had problems downloading dependent libs in the ongoing - so likely some proxy problem

Answer (score 6):

Try to change the version **2.21** insted of **2.16** :

```
org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes jersey-quickstart-webapp 2.21
```

Answer (score 4):

Thanks @sreejith v s . The above mentioned method worked completely fine .I'll repeat the same steps here:-

1. Open Window > Preferences
2. Open Maven > Archetypes
3. Click Add Remote Catalog and add the following:

   3.1 Catalog File: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml

   3.2 Description: maven catalog
4. Restart eclipse

While creating maven project your window might take time to load all the Archetype but it does load all of them because  here we have added the archetype-catalog.xml as remote catalog file.

Answer (score 3):

**One point I want to add, If you are getting following error while installing the archetype showed in image 1**

> Can't resolve Archetype
>   org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes:jersey-quickstart-webapp:2.21
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Could not resolve artifact
>   org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes:jersey-quickstart-webapp:pom:2.21

Image 1:
[image]

**Then before procedding with the solution specified in this page, try to complete [these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30018111/jersey-maven-quickstart-archetype-in-eclipse/32268267#32268267) in eclipse.**

Answer (score 2):

**There could be issue with internet connecting to your eclipse marketplace.
below changes would solve your issue**

Open Window > Preferences>Open Maven > Archetypes
Click on Add Remote Catalog 
Catalog File: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml
Done
Create Project, you should be able to see archtypes of jersey

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure that you have correct entries into your settings.xml which is located at **.m2/settings.xml** or **{maven_home}/conf/settings.xml**

```
<settings>
  <proxies>
   <proxy>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <host>YOUR.PROXY.IP.OR.NAME</host>
      <port>YOUR PROXY PORT</port>
      <username>YOUR PROXY USERNAME (OR EMPTY IF NOT REQUIRED)</username>
      <password>YOUR PROXY PASSWORD (OR EMPTY IF NOT REQUIRED)</password>
      <nonProxyHosts>YOUR PROXY EXCLUSION HOST LIST (OR EMPTY)</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
  </proxies>
</settings>
```

If you are building from your eclipse ensure that **Windows>Preference>{Search Maven}>{Select "User Settings"}>{Update settings.xml location}**

If you are building from command line you may directly use:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes -DarchetypeArticfactId=jersey-quickstart.webapp -DarchetypeVersion=2.28 -DinteractiveMode=false
```

Comment: I am not sure this settings.xml file should go into .m2 directory.  there is a reason why it is hidden.  I know it will work but probably better place is your maven_home/conf/settings.xml.  I tried both ways, both work, just an observation.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked with https instead of http in the below URL
http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml

Can use the 'Verify' option in the Maven > Archetypes to check which one is working

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked with 1.8 Java, earlier I was using Java 11.