# Error in creation of Maven Project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, rest, maven, glassfish

I am trying to create a maven project in eclipse(Eclipse Oxygen JEE). My purpose is to make a REST application in java. I have tried it in two ways:

First, I have tried to create a maven project and to add an archetype (Archetype Group Id: **org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes** Archetype Artifact Id: **jersey-quickstart-webapp**). I have tried all solutions mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31721013/adding-org-glassfish-jersey-archetypes-in-eclipse). I have downloaded XML file(archetype-catalog.xml) from this [URL](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml) and added it as Local Catalog to

`Window > Preferences > Maven > Archetypes`. When I am doing "Update Project" (with Force Update) from `Maven > Update Project...` it is showing following error:

[image]

Second, I have created a "Dynamic Web Project" and then convert it to Maven project by following all steps mentioned [here](https://crunchify.com/how-to-build-restful-service-with-java-using-jax-rs-and-jersey/). At "Step 8", during "Clean", it is showing following error:

[image]

and when I am trying to "Update Project", it is showing following error,

[image]

I am unable to solve this. Please help.

The proxy settings of my eclipse:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried rebuilding the index of the central-repo?

Comment: Are you behind a corporate proxy?

Comment: @Ben, How do I rebuild the index of the central-repo? Do you please explain the steps?

Comment: @lexicore, Yes, I am behind a proxy and I have set up those proxy related things in Eclipse before starting these try outs. I did proxy settings from -->  `Window > Preference > General > Network Connections`

Comment: I have updated my question with the screenshot of proxy settings of my eclipse. Please check.