# How to add jersey archetypes in eclipse in maven?

Tags: java, eclipse, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I am trying to create a maven project but I cant find org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes there. I tried to "Add the new archetype" as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31721013/adding-org-glassfish-jersey-archetypes-in-eclipse).

But it was showing this error-

***Can't resolve Archetype org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes:jersey-quickstart-webapp:2.16 org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Could not resolve artifact***.

I tried adding the archetypes as Remote Catalog as mentioned in the same link but it gives this error on verifying-

***Remote catalog is empty***

Please help me with the issue.

Comment: I just tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31896033/2985643) at the link you provided, and when I clicked the **Verify...** button for _Catalog File_ http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml I got the response _"Found 28987 archetype(s)"_, so it seems to work for me. I am using Eclipse Photon. Which release are you using? Also, update your post if there are any  relevant messages in Eclipse's error log (**Window > Show View > General > Error Log**). Is it possible that you have some firewall or proxy issue?

Comment: Also, it seems that any invalid value in the _Catalog File_ field will generate the misleading error _"Remote catalog is empty"_. The URL **http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml** works, but removing the protocol (**repo1.maven.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml**) or misspelling the file name (**http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/archetypecatalog.xml**) will both misleadingly yield **Remote catalog is empty** rather than **Catalog does not exist**. So double check that you really are entering the correct value in the _Catalog File_ field.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following in Eclipse:

File -> New Maven Project -> Next -> Add Archetype ->

In the new window, fill in the Group ID, Artifact ID and Version with the version that you are using from [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes/jersey-quickstart-webapp/2.28). This is the latest version of a Jersey Webapp at the time of writing this. You can leave Repository URL blank.

It should look something like this:

```
Archetype Group ID: org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes
Archetype Artifact ID: jersey-quickstart-webapp
Version: 2.28
```

Click OK. At this point you can create the new Maven Project or cancel the creation, you will still have the Archetype in either case. I hope this helps.