# RESTful webservice creation in Eclipse

Tags: java, web-services, jax-rs

I want to build a webservice using Java webapi in Eclipse. This is RESTful web service creation.
When I googled I found it that RESTful Java webapi can be built using frameworks like JAX-RS with jersey.

Is it mandatory to use a framework, or can I build a RESTful web service without using frameworks in Java ?
If yes how can I achieve it?

Am I going in right direction by choosing jersey framework?
These created web services will be used by other client applications like ASP.net.

I am very new to Eclipse and Java so Links regarding RESTful webservice creation in Eclipse and any suggestion regarding how to start with this are greatly appreciated.

Comment: not mandatory. you can have plain servlet to write a restful service

Comment: I you want to use jersey framework then i will suggest you to follow the jersey official documentation : https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/getting-started.html

Comment: @sidgate can you suggest me some link regarding this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30020830/2587435

Answer (score 0):

Jersey is the reference implementation of JAX-RS, as such I would say its a good choice.

Creating a service, on your own without a framework, would be reinventing the wheel. You would create your own (partial)-implementation of JAX-RS, then use that.

Clients which connect to your service, do not have to be written in Java.

There is a great book on webservice development with JAX-RS, its called [RESTful Java with JAX-RS 2.0](http://www.amazon.co.uk/RESTful-Java-JAX-RS-Bill-Burke/dp/144936134X/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1450355044&sr=8-1&keywords=jax-rs)

Comment: should i use maven configuration for this or just using jax-rs is enough?.and should client application should use any plugin to acces rest webapi created from jax-rs?as i go deeper into this i have started to get more confusion on what  to use and not

Answer (score 0):

Well, you just to begin with eclipse and jersey so it's basic guide that make simple web service from mkyong(eclipse, maven, tomcat, jersey): http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jersey-hello-world-example/

Practice carefully first to make sense and then back to learn more detail about web service concepts.