# Setiing up jersy Restful maven Project in Eclipse

Tags: rest, maven, http, jersey

Today I am started with **Restful** Practice , I got Stuck in **Setting up Restful maven project**.  I am creating a Maven project,In Select Archetype window i am not getting any option related to  **jersey** in filter text box during search of jersey API...
Steps I Followed after watching Below Video Tutorial :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=skltzZH7i4w&list=PLqq-6Pq4lTTZh5U8RbdXq0WaYvZBz2rbn&index=11

1. Click on New option ---> other
2. Search for MAven and click on Maven Project
3. Click next---- again click on next
4. In Filter text box I am searching for "Jersey", (I am not getting   options related to jerseyglassfish, I am expecting one option on search name

> "com.glassfish.jersey.archetypes"

containing two different 2 artifact ID

is this need any plugin Installation or library attachment ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jersey Maven quickstart archetype in Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30018111/jersey-maven-quickstart-archetype-in-eclipse)

Comment: @peeskillet : thanks buddy. I followed steps what you commented and it worked :)