# Error while creating Maven-JERSEY Project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jersey, maven-archetype

I am newbie to maven. I am trying to create a maven project with archetype **org.glassfish.jersey.archetype** in eclipse. It is giving error as shown in images.

**Could not Resolve Archetype**

[image: Could not Resolve Archetype]

I have already followed the answer at these links "[Jersey Maven quickstart archetype in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30018111/jersey-maven-quickstart-archetype-in-eclipse/32268267#32268267). "
"[Create a Maven project in Eclipse complains "Could not resolve archetype"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15506043/create-a-maven-project-in-eclipse-complains-could-not-resolve-archetype)"

I tried it using proxy settings, still it is not working. Here is the content inside settings file(xml). I have also updated this file in maven user settings.

```
<settings>
<proxies>
   <proxy>
      <id>example-proxy</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <host>proxy.example.com</host>
      <port>8080</port>
      <username>proxyuser</username>
      <password>somepassword</password>
      <nonProxyHosts>www.google.com|*.example.com</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
  </proxies>
</settings>
```

Also I am not able to add "REMOTE CATALOG" using this link. "http //repo1.maven.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml". It shows error that "REMOTE CATALOG IS EMPTY". Here is the image for the same.

**Remote Catalog is Empty Error**

[image: Remote Catalog is Empty Error]

I have used local catalog to get the archetypes.

Comment: Are you behind a corporate proxy ?

Comment: Yes, But how does it matter?

Comment: It does , if you have a dynamic proxy (.pac) your downloads of dependencies will be blocked. You will have to look at some option like CNTLM  or wagon to have a work around this. Hence it matters

Comment: Okay, Actually i am not aware of CNTLM or wagon. Can u please tell me what's this

Comment: Now that it matters , you should refer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23539048/maven-behind-a-auto-generated-proxy/24540105#24540105

Comment: Okay Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

You can download the catalog file directly using link http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml and save it on your local system.

Then add this file as local catalog in eclipse (Windows -> Preferences -> Maven -> Archetype -> Add Local Catalog ) as shown in the image below .

[image]

Then choose this catalog for archetype.