# getting following error on Adding org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes in eclipse version Oxygen

Tags: eclipse, web-services, jersey, m2eclipse, jersey-client

[image: Getting below error on eclipse when trying to add jersey]

[image: I am trying to create a maven project in eclipse. I am trying create a archetype as shown in the image but getting the below error.]

I have tried everything but unable to add it.

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32268267/2587435)?

Comment: Yes, i have tried. It didnt work.